# SQL Query Separate Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a sql good working like this.

```
SELECT  B.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + A.TEKLIF_NO2 AS 'TEKLIF',
B.MUS_K_ISIM, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.ISL_TAR,103) AS 'TARIH',
SUM(ISNULL(CAST(A.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) AS 'YATAN', 
    (CASE WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS 'KUR',
    D.AVUKAT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.ICRA_TAR,103) AS 'İCRA TARİHİ', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),C.HACIZ_TAR,103) AS 'HACİZ TARİHİ'

FROM YAZ..MARDATA.BIR_TAHSIL A, YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF B, TAKIP C, AVUKAT D, P_TAKIP_SR E

WHERE A.TEKLIF_NO1 = B.TEKLIF_NO1
AND A.TEKLIF_NO2 = B.TEKLIF_NO2
AND B.HESAP_NO = D.HESAP
AND D.HESAP = A.HESAP_NO
```

And i add a date range with code like this.

```
if (txtBoxText1 != "")
    {
        strQuery = strQuery + " AND A.ISL_TAR >= @S_TARIH_B";

      dt_stb = DateTime.Parse(txtBoxText1);
      myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_TARIH_B", dt_stb);
    }

    if (txtBoxText2 != "")
    {
        strQuery = strQuery + " AND A.ISL_TAR <= @S_TARIH_S";
      dt_sts = DateTime.Parse(txtBoxText2);
      myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_TARIH_S", dt_sts);
    }
```

For the last i add `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY  B.HESAP_NO, A.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + A.TEKLIF_NO2,A.ISL_TAR,B.DOVIZ_KOD, B.HESAP_NO, B.MUS_K_ISIM, D.AVUKAT, C.ICRA_TAR, C.HACIZ_TAR
```

But this query gettig result for example like this (part of some)

```
HESAP_NO       MUS_K_ISIM     YATAN  Date
889          2M LOJİSTİK      7090   28/03/2010
```

Just getting one record for 28/03/2010. But in the database, in this date, there are two records.

```
HESAP_NO       MUS_K_ISIM     YATAN  Date
889          2M LOJİSTİK      5000   28/03/2010
889              2M LOJİSTİK      2090   28/03/2010
```

As you see (5000 + 2090 = 7090) adding all YATAN (number) and getting one record the top query.

What i want is, the getting all records in the same date like second result.

```
  HESAP_NO     MUS_K_ISIM     YATAN  Date
    889          2M LOJİSTİK      5000   28/03/2010
    889              2M LOJİSTİK      2090   28/03/2010
```

How can i do that?

Regars,
Soner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of your SUM function in your SELECT:

```
SUM(ISNULL(CAST(A.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) AS 'YATAN',
```

Try replacing this with:

```
ISNULL(CAST(A.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(A.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0) AS 'YATAN',
```

Which also means you should be able to remove your `GROUP BY` clause.  This should provide you with the results for any unique results in your tables.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your code and in your description, you should probably remove `SUM()` as nybbler has suggested and add these columns to `GROUP BY`:

```
A.ODENEN_ANAPARA, A.FAIZ, A.BSMV, A.GECIKME_FAIZ, A.GECIKME_BSMV
```